# No tests executed JUNIT Netbeans 8.2

Tags: java, netbeans, junit

I have libraries imported JUNIT 4.12 and Hamcrest 1.3 and test folder setup. Sources pointing to the right test package folder. I would run test with Shift+F6 for each Java test file and it would execute all tests in that java file. After a restart of my computer, I followed same procedure to run tests only to get "No tests executed". What could be the reason and solution.

```
package test1;
import hello.*;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class hellotest {
private jj j1;

@Before
public void runBeforeEachTest(){
    j1 = new jj();
    j1.setName("cur");
    j1.setComp("goo");
}

@Test
public void testProp(){
    String name = j1.getName();
    String cmp = j1.getComp();
    assertEquals("cur", name);
    assertEquals("goo", cmp);
}

}
```

Same project without any modification works fine on another computer. Trying to re-install Netbeans 8.2 , but it does not uninstall , it gives error "Java SE Development Kit(JDK) was not found on this computer" JDK 6 is required for uninstalling the Netbeans IDE. 
This is strange since to install NetBeans 8.2 JDK 8 is installed but during uninstallation JDK 6 it is looking for. Question is how to uninstall Netbeans?

Comment: Seeing the test files you're attempting to run would help, too.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have to right click your project and **Test**. The same tool is located on the navigation bar **Run / Test Project (project)** since you have selected a project as active.

You can either use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>. Your shortcut using <kbd>Shift</kbd> is wrong and I have no idea what it should do (check the **Options**).

This guarantee to start all the tests. You can either create your test suite defining the "pack" of test instances.

Comment: Each java file under test has options Run File Shift + F6 (this is how it was working fine before now it does not work) and has another option Test File Ctrl + F6 (this never worked for me). At the project level right click Test(Alt + F6 ) never ever worked for me.

Comment: Where are your test files located?

Comment: Projects view :                                                                                                            Hello                                                                                                      
    Source Packages                                                                                       
    Test Packages                                                                                      
         test1                                                                               
             hellotest.java

Comment: Hello > Test Packages > test1 > hellotest.java